# Compute Covariance Matrix Manually (without Numpy np.cov)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to Python and am trying to compute the covariance matrix for a 3x3 matrix manually. Below is my code:

```
df = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]) # example 3x3 matrix
means = df.mean
cov = []
for j in range(len(means)):
    sum = 0
    covs = []
    for k in range(len(means)):
        terms = ( (df[i][j] - means[j]) * (df[i][k] - means[k]) for i in range(len(means)) )
        covariance  = sum(terms) / len(means)
        covs.append(covariance)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-3e38715077d0> in <module>
      1 means = df.mean
      2 Cov = []
----> 3 for j in range(len(means)):
      4     sum = 0
      5     covs = []

TypeError: object of type 'method' has no len()
```

EDIT: I just updated to df.mean() per the suggestion, but now I receive the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-9d6e2f3103c9> in <module>
      6     for k in range(len(means)):
      7         terms = ( (df[i][j] - means[j]) * (df[i][k] - means[k]) for i in range(len(means)) )
----> 8         covariance  = sum(terms) / len(means)
      9         covs.append(covariance)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Would appreciate any help/explanation for how to fix my calculation! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To compute the mean, use `means = df.mean()` (with open and close parenthesis), otherwise you are getting the method to compute the mean, that's what raises the error.

Also, you are overwritting the sum operation `sum = 0`, I would use `total_sum = 0`.

Comment: Thanks @ronkov. I now get the following error: 'int' object is not callable for the covariance  = sum(terms) / len(means) line

Comment: You are overwritting the sum operation in the line `sum = 0`, I would use `total_sum = 0`.